# How to add +1 to variable every 10 seconds in Processing?

Tags: processing, milliseconds

Excuse my ignorance, but I ran into a problem that turned out to be challenging for my current knowledge in programming with Processing, even though the idea is quite simple. You see, I need to add 1 unit to a variable every 10 seconds. This is the code:

```java
int i = 0;

void setup()
{
  frameRate(60);
}

void draw()
{

  int time = (millis() % 10000) / 1000;

  if (time == 9)
  {
    i++;
  } else {}

  System.out.println("-------------------------------\n" +
                     "Timer: " + time + "\n"
                   + "Adding 1 every 10 seconds: : " + i + "\n"
                   + "-------------------------------");
}
```

The problem is that because `draw()` loops 60 times per second, as soon as `time` reaches 9 the second it last makes the `if` statement to be executed 60 times and it ends adding 60 to `i` every 10 seconds and I just need to be adding 1.

I tried to apply some kind of algorithm that subtracts the unnecessary numbers as they increase like so:

```java
int i = 1;
int toSubstract = 0; //Variable for algorithm

void setup()
{
  frameRate(60);
}

void draw()
{

  int time = (millis() % 10000) / 1000;

  if (time == 9)
  {
    i++;
    algToSubstract();
  } else {}



  System.out.println("-------------------------------\n" +
                     "Timer: " + time + "\n"
                   + "Adding 1 every 10 seconds: : " + i + "\n"
                   + "-------------------------------");
}

void algToSubstract() //<--- This is the algorithm
{
  i = i - toSubstract;
  toSubstract++;

  if (toSubstract > 59)
  {
    toSubstract = 0;
  } else {}
}
```

...but I couldn't make it work. The idea was something like this:

`time` reaches 9, `if` statement executes, `i` = 1 and `toSubstract` = 0.

`i` increases 1 so `i` = 2.

`i = i - toSusbract` (`i` = 2 - 0 so `i` = 2).

`toSusbract` increases 1 so `toSusbract` = 1.

`i` increases 1 so `i` = 3.

`i = i - toSusbract` (`i` = 3 - 1 so `i` = 2).

`toSusbract` increases 1 so `toSusbract` = 2.

... Process continues...

`toSubstract` gets bigger than 59 so it is restarted to 0.

`time` stops being 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ringo has a solution that's perfectly fine.

Another way you can do this easily is:

```java
bool addOnce = false;
void draw()
{
  int time = (millis() % 10000) / 1000;
  if (time == 9)
  {
      if(!addOnce) {
          addOnce = true;
          i++;
      }
  } else { addOnce = false; }
}
```

As long as `time == 9`, we'll only get through `if(!addOnce)` one time.

After it changes, we reset the flag.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine general approaches, but they don't take advantage of the features that Processing provides for you.

For example, you could use the `frameCount` variable to check how many frames have elapsed. Since `draw()` is called 60 times per second, 10 seconds is 600 frames. Something like this:

```java
void draw(){
  if(frameCount % 600 == 0){
    // 10 seconds has elapsed
  }
}
```

Another way to do this is to store the last time 10 seconds elapsed, and then check that against the current time to see if 10 seconds has elapsed since then. Something like this:

```java
int previousTime = 0;

void draw(){
   if(millis() > previousTime + 10*1000){
      // 10 seconds has elapsed
      previousTime = millis();
   }
}
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Answer (score 0):

You could store the last number of seconds in a static (or global) variable, and only increment `i` when the current number of seconds is higher than the `oldsecs`

```
void draw() {
    static int oldsecs = 0;
    int secs = millis() / 1000;
    if (secs > oldsecs) {
        i++;
        oldsecs = secs;
    }
    ...
```

Assuming the language is C, and the *int* type is not overflowed by the number of seconds.

Comment: The language is Processing. Note the [tag:processing] tag.